# Tooltip on data cell from ajax based data for bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

Can someone explain how to add a tooltip for a data cell with data coming back from an ajax request.

I could not find anything in the documentation:

http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/

I know how to achieve this with data populated in a loop via HTML tags but there doesn’t seem to be an easy way to do it when data is auto populated as it comes back from an ajax request.

This is how my table is setup:

```
<table id="stockLineTable" class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped" data-toggle="table" data-classes="" data-toolbar="#filter-bar"
    data-search="true"
    data-show-refresh="true"
    data-show-columns="true"
    data-minimum-count-columns="2"
    data-pagination="true"
    data-page-list="[25, 50, 100, 200]"
    data-show-footer="true"
    data-show-export="true"
    data-show-filter="true"
    data-click-to-select="true"
    data-page-size="25"
    data-export-types="['csv', 'doc', 'excel']" style="display: none;"
    data-url="/Api/StockLine/GetStockLines"
    data-side-pagination="server"
    data-query-params-type=""
    data-sort-order="desc"
    data-row-style="rowStyle"
    data-query-params="queryParams">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="state" data-radio="true"></th>
            <th data-sortable="true" data-field="RowIndex" data-visible="false" data-switchable="false"></th>
            <th data-sortable="true" data-field="StockDetailID" data-visible="true" data-switchable="true">@Resource.ID</th>
            <th data-sortable="true" data-visible="true" data-switchable="true" data-field="Name">@Resource.Stock @Resource.Line</th>
            <th data-sortable="true" data-field="Size" data-switchable="true" data-visible="true">@Resource.Size</th>
            <th data-sortable="true" data-field="StockCategoryID" data-switchable="true" data-visible="true">@Resource.Category</th>
            <th data-sortable="true" data-field="StockLevel" data-sorter="dateSorter">@Resource.Qty @Resource.InStock</th>
            <th data-sortable="true" data-field="MinQuantityLevel">@Resource.Qty @Resource.OnOrder</th>
            <th data-sortable="false" data-field="Controls" data-switchable="false" data-visible="true"></th>
            <th data-sortable="false" data-field="AdHoc" data-switchable="false" data-visible="false"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Where you need ajaxbased tooltip? and which event you need that?

Comment: I need it in the data contained in the rows I know it is possible to do in the headers but there doesn't seem to be anything for the data rows

Answer (score 0):

After battling with the source I found that the quickest solution was to edit the source to achieve what I wanted having seen that there wasn’t anything available to enable in the library.

I had to edit the bootstrap table library for myself to accommodate for this solution.

For anyone who wants to know how to achieve tooltips on data cells this is what I did to resolve it.

Original source:
https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/blob/develop/src/bootstrap-table.js

Before:

```
text = that.options.cardView ? ['<div class="card-view">',
    that.options.showHeader ? sprintf('<span class="title" %s>%s</span>', style,
        getPropertyFromOther(that.columns, 'field', 'title', field)) : '',
    sprintf('<span class="value">%s</span>', value),
    '</div>'
].join('') : [sprintf('<td%s %s %s %s %s %s %s>',
    id_, class_, style, data_, rowspan_, colspan_, title_), 
    value,
    '</td>'
].join('');
```

After:

In the initBody() method after line 1773 I edited up to line 1784 the following:

```
var tooltip = value.length > 15 && field != "Controls";
var displayeValue = tooltip ? value.substring(0, 15) + "..." : value;
text = that.options.cardView ? ['<div class="card-view">',
    that.options.showHeader ? sprintf('<span class="bt-title" %s>%s</span>', style,
        getPropertyFromOther(that.columns, 'field', 'title', field)) : '',
    sprintf('<span class="value">%s</span>', value),
    '</div>'
].join('') : [sprintf('<td%s %s %s %s %s %s>', 
    id_, class_, style, data_, rowspan_, 'title="' + (tooltip ? value : '') + '"'),
    displayeValue,
    '</td>'
].join('');
```

The above will show a HTML tooltip when the text exceeds 15 characters.